# ssh repeating text sometimes

Tags: bash, ssh, openssh

My ssh connection is repeating text sometimes. Not what I input, but the normal text
Like this:

> `pi@myserver:~ $ pi@myserver:~ $`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if you're executing some code and pressing ENTER or keyboard interrupts a lot, my way of fixing it is either pressing ENTER again or `clear` to clean up the terminal.